# C++ Sending a simple signal in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, kill, signals, pid

is there an equivalent to the function kill() on Windows?

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

If not, would it be possible to test if a process is running based on its PID?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't have signals in the unix sense.

You can use `OpenProcess` to check if a process exists - If it succeeds, or fails with an access error, then the process exists.

```
bool processExists(DWORD ProcessID) {
  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, ProcessID);
  if (hProcess != NULL) {
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return true;
  }
  // If the error code is access denied, the process exists but we don't have access to open a handle to it.
  return GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No signals in Windows.  If true killing is intended then use TerminateProcess().  You need a handle to the process, get that from OpenProcess().  You'll need to ask for the PROCESS_TERMINATE access right.  CloseHandle() to close the handle.

Comment: One side comment: Using TerminateProcess is like using a sledgehammer - it does exactly what you'd think it does, it terminates the process.  The process doesn't get to do any cleanup, it's terminated.