# How to simulate Ctrl+C combination using C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, simulate, ctrl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)
>   [How to effectively kill a process in C++ (Win32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916574/how-to-effectively-kill-a-process-in-c-win32)
>   [C++ Sending a simple signal in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289549/c-sending-a-simple-signal-in-windows)

I have a java console application, this application starts to shutdown when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Could you please tell me, how I can simulate pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> from my C++ application if I know only **pid** and have process **handle**?

As I understood, I must send `SIGINT` signal to process, how can I do it?

p.s. Solutions on SO are not working!

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using? What solutions are not working?

Comment: On POSIX systems `man 3 kill` should give you all you need.

Comment: @Burgos, OS windows. Solutions about sending ctrl-c hex to process input stream, these solutions only paste ^C in console line

Comment: Take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows or simply call TerminateProcess

Comment: Or event better http://stackoverflow.com/q/813086/912144

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1916574/566608 p.s. Solution on SO, expecially the one marked as answers do work!

Answer (score 1):

On posix by using

```
kill(pid, SIGINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) for that. You need the process id (`pid`) of your java application

```
pid_t java_app;
kill(java_app, SIGINT);
```